# Does Romance exist between Shiv-Parvati and Vishnu-Lakhshmi?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, lakshmi, parvati, love

Romance definitely exist between Krishna and Radha.

But my question is regarding other two couples -

1. Shiva-Parvati
2. Vishnu-Lakshmi

Or Are their relationship platonic ?

Platonic relationship can exist between male and female.

Comment: For Vishnu/Lakshmi, see [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55527/why-did-rama-love-sita-so-much/55531#55531) answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Love between Shiva and Shakti is mentioned in Siva purana and several other places

### Siva Purana Section 2.2 - Rudra-saṃhitā (2): Satī-khaṇḍa, Chapter 22

> **68-70. Śiva found place and pleasure only with Satī. He found no pleasure in sacrifices or the Vedas or penances. Day and night Satī
> stared into the face of Śiva and He, the great lord, stared into the
> face of Satī. Thus by their mutual association Kālī and Śiva nurtured
> the tree of love, sprinkling it with waters of emotion.**